# Alert event does not get results

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm a beginner in this whole world, and I'm trying to implement a function in my application. I found a project available for download and I changed all the code to my favor, but at the end of it I came across something, which seems simple, but I was very much immobilized. After cropping the image, a 'result' link is generated. I need to get this result and send it to my application via SetWebString, but it did not work so I created something basic to be shown an event with that result, but I can not at all. I spent all night searching the net and found nothing. All necessary information is at the end of the code. I do not remember where I got this code, so I will not credit the author here, but anyone who wants to copy and modify it at will. This code had a lot more functions, but I removed it to meet only what I want. To use in App Inventor, I preferred to put 90% of the code in a single file. HTML, JavaScript and CSS and Stack said the code is great to put here, so I'll put his link from Dropbox. The code is great, but what I want to see is at the end of it. There I have a result and I want Alert to show me this result. Thank you in advance.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/syxlg3cb4rb1630/index.html?dl=0

Comment: You can't be serious, do you really expect us to grab an unknown file from dropbox and then just hope we find your problem and then come with up a solution? Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry man, it's because Stack did not let me put the code here, he said it was too big. So in the above information I said that the part that needs to be parsed is at the end of the code. The only function I need is to launch an Alert from a result. This whole thing is well at the end of the code, but I spent hours trying to do it and I could not, so I came here to ask for help.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a function in the angular controller and call the $scope value in it
(function() {

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ImageCropper'])  

.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
     $scope.Cortar = function() {
         alert($scope.imgSrc);
     }
     ...
```

Change your code to

```
<button ng-click="initCrop = true;Cortar()">Crop</button>
```

Comment: Good morning, thank you! I got to change the code, but it did not work. In the Firefox console there is no error. I saw it here on the Angle.module Stack, but it still did not work. I've changed the code in Dropbox too, if you can help me.


<button ng-click="initCrop = true; Cortar()">Crop</button>
 </div>

<script>
function AngularCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.Cortar = function() {
      alert("David Benner"); }
}
</script>

Comment: Even so, unfortunately I could not make it work. I ran a lot behind this, and I studied a lot, but it was not enough. Thank you for your help :)